# CUSTOM VIEW Parallax scrolling like Instagram Profile Page (in Android)

Tags: android, xml, scroll, instagram, parallax

I have been searching for a solution on how to make a **parallax scrolling UI just like on the Instagram Profile page.**

[image: Instagram Profile Page]

The top of the layout includes profile info section and there is a tab layout underneath. And on the bottom, there is a recyclerview. When recyclerview starts to scroll, the profile info section goes up simultaneously.

I found some examples about that, but they only have an imageview parallax(an imageview instead of a profile info section).

[Imageview parallax example](https://medium.com/android-news/parallax-scrolling-header-tabs-android-tutorial-2cc6e40aa257)

I couldn't find any other clear solution to this. Is there a way to implement this layout?

**Of course, there is since Instagram did it already but how :D**

Thank you in advance for all your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a parallax scrolling layout by checking out couple of repos. I saw @evgenkr47's answer after I implemented it but his answer totally right also. Thank you again.

Here is the layout, maybe anyone else also needs it in the future.

[Parallax Scrolling Layout](https://github.com/talhaoz/Instagram-Profile-Page-Parallax-Scrolling-Layout)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CoordinationLayout + AppBarLayout + CollapsingToolBarLayout inside ConstraintLayout

For example:

```
<ConstraintLayout1>
  <ToolBar-> profile nickname
  <CoordinationLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
    <CollapsingToolBarLayout> 
      <ConstraintLayout2> - hidden part
        --Hidden content--
      </ConstraintLayout2> 
    <ConstrainLayout3>
      <TabLayout/> - will stick to the toolbar
      <FragmentContainerView/>
    </ConstrainLayout3>
    </CollapsingToolBarLayout> 
    </AppBarLayout>
  </CoordinationLayout>
</ConstraintLayout1>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, solved the problem by using the same kind of layout @evgenkr47

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).